# How to find out where to get a dll (PkgBldr.Tool.dll in this case)

Tags: dll, windows-10-universal, windows-10-iot-core

At a dead end in the [windows hardware and IoT-Core forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowshardware/en-US/e9d23187-70d8-409c-9655-fde0d727a9f5/errors-creating-basic-image-for-iotcore-arm-using-iotadkaddonkit?forum=HardwareBoards), I thought I'd ask the experts! Which spy knows how to find out where I can get/install the required PkgBldr.Tool.dll.

Please see:
[GitHub-Issue](https://github.com/ms-iot/iot-adk-addonkit/issues/47)

Comment: I have two computers, both with ADK and WDK installed, however, one has PkgBldr.Tool.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Tools\bin\i386 folder, and the other does not. Not sure about the differences though.

Comment: Thanks. I have the identical situation here. Both machines seem to have the same installations and versions applied, but one of them is missing these crucial binaries. There must be a way to look up which kit this dll is distributed by. That would get us much further in the investigation. But where to find this info?